# Azure Devops multi-configuration with SSH service connection not working

Tags: azure-devops

Need to create release pipeline using multi-configuration that needs to run steps on multiple servers using SSH. (Each server should be a value in the multi-configuration).
The SSH service connection parameter of the task uses a variable (which is multi-configured with the names of the service connections)

When running the release jobs, the SSH task fails with "Error: Endpoint auth data not present: 7dfbca54-6025-4265-866c-9abd76b02e81,7b595350-166f-4e45-996c-795793315182"

If my Multi-configuration only have one value, it works.

From the error message, looks like the multi-configuration variable is not splitted. Although, the Service connection ids are detected and replaced in the variable.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[config of multi-configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdr4q.png)

[multi-configuration variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fifZ.png)

[SSH task using multi-configuration variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDslE.png)

[list of SSH service connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxJo9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. I set up a variable called ServerName with `hughl-api20s,hughl-api21s` as value. When I use $(ServerName) in the SSH server connection field of the ssh task, I also get `Error: Endpoint auth data not present`. I think this could be a bug.

[image]

As a workaround you can run two agent jobs and select a specific service connection in each agent job.

You can report a problem to the product team on this issue in the [Develop Community Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Comment: Hi Hugh!
I've been informed by a MSFT contact that this is by design for security reason to make sure the user creating the job have access to the endpoint.
I hope they found a way to enable this as it is one of the biggest usage of multi-configuration that I thought using in release.

Comment: You could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.